# What does it mean when the logcat shows: system_server E failed to add asset path?

Tags: php, android-studio, xampp, retrofit

I made an app which uses retrofit to access my localhost server and post data on a user. The code from the app works because I tried it on my virtual device and on my phone with the website https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

the php works because I tried it with postman and it works

But when I try to connect I get this error in my logcat

```
SDAgentPac...teReceiver system_server                        E  Not going to handle 'com.example.retrofitviewsphpsql'!
2023-12-25 14:39:19.521  4227-4306  ResourcesManager        system_server                        E  failed to add asset path /data/app/com.example.retrofitviewsphpsql-MhzxSZfwEKBGUjg11dD7tA==/base.apk
2023-12-25 14:39:20.900 14882-14882 AppCompatDelegate       com.example.retrofitviewsphpsql      D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
2023-12-25 14:39:21.949  4227-4227  SDAgentPac...teReceiver system_server                        E  Not going to handle 'com.example.retrofitviewsphpsql'!
2023-12-25 14:39:22.100 14882-14969 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.retrofitviewsphpsql      D  HWUI GL Pipeline
2023-12-25 14:39:22.133 14882-14951 AndroidRuntime          com.example.retrofitviewsphpsql      E  FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.retrofitviewsphpsql, PID: 14882
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(HttpUrl.java:1332)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(HttpUrl.java:917)
                                                                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:506)
                                                                                                        at com.example.retrofitviewsphpsql.RetrofitInstance$api$2.invoke(RetrofitInstance.kt:11)
                                                                                                        at com.example.retrofitviewsphpsql.RetrofitInstance$api$2.invoke(RetrofitInstance.kt:9)
                                                                                                        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
                                                                                                        at com.example.retrofitviewsphpsql.RetrofitInstance.getApi(RetrofitInstance.kt:9)
                                                                                                        at com.example.retrofitviewsphpsql.MainActivity$postRequest$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:102)
                                                                                                        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
2023-12-25 14:39:22.167 14882-14896 zygote                  com.example.retrofitviewsphpsql      I  Background concurrent copying GC freed 4750(1005KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 1654KB/3MB, paused 1.265ms total 132.302ms
2023-12-25 14:39:22.172 14882-14882 InputTransport          com.example.retrofitviewsphpsql      D  Input channel constructed: fd=56
```

I've looked around and the Fatal exception seems to be something wrong with the coroutines, but the 'Not going to handle 'app name' is new.

I have checked the address that I try to access which is

```
const val BASE = "IP/MyApplication/v1/registerUser.php"
```

and the POST function

```
@POST("/posts")
    suspend fun createPost(
        @Body user: User
    ):Response<User>
```

Is it a problem with those urls?

Comment: What this seems to say is that is that you tried to handle a URL called "com.example.retrofitviewsphpsql", which of course is not a URL.

Comment: The app is supposed to access the BASE url. Why does it use the name of the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the path of the url was wrong
It needed the base needed to be like this

```
"http://ip/appname/v1/"
```

and the @POST("/namefile.php")

Comment: Consider using `https://…` instead of `http://…`